# "Пороть чушь"

Tags: фразеология

"Пороть чушь" — значит говорить глупости. А каково происхождение этого выражения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В русском языке есть синонимичный фразеологизм "дичь пороть (нести)": 
Ср. Без заминки, где придется,
Всюду порет дичь
И поэтому зовется
Милый Петр Ильич!
В.С. Курочкин. Общий знакомый.
Ср. Такую дичь несет,
Что уши вянут.
Крылов. Мешок. 
Цитаты отсюда: http://slov.com.ua/frazeologycheskyy_slovar_myhelsona/page/dich_porotnesti.2451/

Словарь Фасмера, надеюсь, поможет разобраться в происхождении этого выражения.

чушь

ж., род. п. -и, также чужь. Последняя форма, возм., получена в результате вторичного сближения с чужо́й. Первую можно было бы возвести вместе с нов.-в.-н. Stuss "ерунда" к еврейско-нем. štuss от др.-еврейск. šǝṭûϑ "глупость, безумие" (относительно последнего см. Литтман 47; Клюге-Гётце 604). •• [Маловероятно. Скорее можно предположить связь с чу́шка, чу́ха I, от которого данное слово могло образоваться довольно поздно. – Т.]

пороть - поро́ть дичь, чушь, укр. поро́ти, блр. поро́ць, др.-русск. пороти, порю "**разрезать, потрошить**", цслав. прати, порɪѫ "резать", болг. по́ря "разрезаю", сербохорв. по̀рити, по̀ри̑м "пороть, распарывать", словен. práti, pórjem "пороть (по шву)", чеш. párati "**пороть, распарывать**", слвц. раrаt᾽ – то же, польск. próć, porzę "пороть, разрезать", в.-луж. próć, роru, н.-луж. projś. Праслав. *porti,* porjǫ; связано чередованием гласных с русск.-цслав. напери "**проткнул**", разперу = разпорɪѫ, далее сюда же греч. πείρω (*реri̯ō), аор. ἔπαρον "***пронзать (мечом, взглядом), прокалывать***", πόρος "проход", гот. fаrаn "ехать" (Мейе, МSL 19, 135; Траутман, ВSW 206; Маценауэр, LF 13, 190; Миккола, Ursl. Gr. 3, 80).

Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс. М. Р. Фасмер. 1964—1973.